# Getting latest sensor value in set of devices

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with following schema:

```
meshSetVersion integer
gatewayMAC text
deviceMAC text
sensorID integer
sensorValue text
timestamp time
```

First I find the latest meshSetVersion with:

```
(select max(meshSetVersion) from test where gatewayMAC='XXX') as lastV
```

Then I find it's devices:

```
select distinct gatewayMAC, deviceMAC from test
where gatewayMAC='xxx' and meshSetVersion=lastV
```

Then I need to get latest sensorValue of each ID by timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses `distinct on`.  I think this is the logic that you want:

```
select distinct on (sensorId) t.*
from test t
where t.meshSetVersion = (select max(t2.meshSetVersion)
                          from test t2
                          where t2.gatewayMach = 'xxx'
                         )
order by sensorId, timestamp desc;
```